# Edit files in .zip archive using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, ftp

I want to have a special function in my website, operated by a button click.

I need the function to download a .zip archive from the website's FTP server, and then edit some of the files with parameters from the user's input on the site.

I have a few questions about this process:

1) How should I do that? JavaScript or PHP? Because I saw that JavaScript cannot really edit files.

2) The website is built from a few pages where the user writes things in text fields. I need to save the user's input somehow through about 5 HTML pages, so I would be able to use this input in the editing function and to "paste" them inside a file. How can I save this input through those 5 HTML pages?

3) After the function ends with editing the files, I need to save the edited files, and pack all files, including the ones I didn't edited, inside a new .zip archive and to upload the new .zip archive to the website's FTP server. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.
Maybe you expected a free code writing service here?

Comment: Zipping files cannot be done with Javascript I think. But all this can be done using PHP. You should take a look at it, it's great.

Comment: @Cagy79 No, I didn't expect a free code writing service. I need basically some recommendations, like in what language to do the function, or in what method to save the input. Believe me. I don't look for someone to write my code for free.

Comment: "JavaScript cannot really edit files" - It certainly can. What you cannot do is use browser JavaScript to manipulate the file system (it's an obvious security measure) but that's not what you want to do anyway. I wouldn't be surprised that someone wrote a library to manipulate ZIP files in a browser, but I bet it's pretty resource intensive. Plus, does PHP need to fetch the file by FTP, doesn't it have direct access through the server disk?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use PHP.
2. You can make POST-request to web-server. and
   write PHP script for it.
3. You should install php-zip module on
   your web-server and use these functions
   http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php
4. If you want download zip file from FTP. You should install php-ftp module and use these functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

P.S. I guess your should hire web-developer for it

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo from the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php)

```
> <?php
> 
> $zip = new ZipArchive(); $filename = "./test112.zip";
> 
> if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
>     exit("cannot open <$filename>\n"); }
> 
> $zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test
> string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
> $zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test
> string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n"); $zip->addFile($thisdir .
> "/too.php","/testfromfile.php"); echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles .
> "\n"; echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n"; $zip->close(); ?>
```